# It is possible to get my current location via the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to build a portion into my personal website that shows the locations I have tagged in my posts on facebook. My understanding is that I need to do an oAuth Request on the server to get the AccessToken:

## **UPDATE**

I built a php file that gets a file with the token in it and refreshes it. I can call this file with a cron job every hour and have an unlimited token. It looks like this:

```
    $appID = "APPID";
    $appSecret = "APPSECRET";
    $currentToken = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/token.txt");
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$appID."&client_secret=".$appSecret."&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=".$currentToken;
    $ci = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $newtoken = curl_exec($ci);
    curl_close ($ci);

    $newtoken = str_replace("access_token=","",$newtoken);
    $newtoken = substr($newtoken, 0,strpos($newtoken, "&expires=",0));

    if($newtoken == "")
    {
        echo "error";
    }
    else
    {
        $file = __DIR__."/token.txt";
        file_put_contents($file, $newtoken);
        echo $newtoken;
    }
```

Comment: You need an access token. What's your console.log(data) returning? Is data a string or a JSON object. If data is coming through as an object, it needs to be data.access_token (or w/e your variable name is) when you pass it as the value for the access_token parameter in your FB.api call.

Comment: I don't want to post my response cause it contains the appID, but basically it looks like AppID|RandomString

Comment: Like it's not even an array they return back that is why I was doing the str_replace() in the functions.php page

Comment: Is 'data' a JSON object or a string with *only* the access_token? You're passing the data variable to your API call as if it is only a string holding your access token. It sounds like it holds your app id as well, in which case you need to pass only the access token portion of the data object. Check your browser's network requests and make sure that the API call is sending all of the data in the URL properly.

Comment: it is just a string.

Comment: How long is an access token usually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Access Token has the form `{app_id}|{app_secret}`, you're not using a User Access Token, but an App Access Token.

Seems like you don't implement the proper Login process to gather the User Access Token. Stick to the provided sample code of the FB PHP SDK.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference between the tokens. I have made my own token check system that can cycle the refresh token. It is silly that an app access token isn't a long lasting token that can be used to refresh indefinitely...

I really don't want to use the PHP SDK. So I am storing an somewhat valid token in my DB, and I have a trigger that runs every 30 minutes that updates the token in there.

Comment: I think you misunderstand some things here. App Access Tokens are eternal, User Access Tokens (short-lived) are valid for two hours, long-lived ones 60 days. You need a User Access Token to access `/me/feed`. You can generate a long-lived User Access Token via the Graph Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending